# How do i stop my app from accessing the database numerous times for each cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a UITableViewCell, which receives a pointer to an object in the database. That object has it's own objects on a one-to-one relationship. I want to know how I can access various bits of information from these objects without it accessing the database each time. Sort of along the same lines as 'am I able to load the data in one go so it's all ready to go, as part of the pointer, rather than something that needs to be loaded from the database'?

Comment: The question is unclear, in what way are you "accessing the database" if you already have the objects?

Comment: Is this causing an actual performance issue? Core Data does cache results, and other than that you should be careful about memory use on mobile devices. Unless there is an actual performance issue, I wouldn't mind looking up data frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`NSCache`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to cache the data. Before going to DB, check if the data is in the cache. If it is not, read the DB and put the results in the cache; next time the access is going to be almost instantaneous.

You can also use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) to access the database: it caches results for you.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew,

You can set your fetch request to not load your items as faults, i.e. make all the data available instead of cached in the row cache, by using `-returnsObjectsAsFaults`. Also, you can prefetch the properties in relationships by using `-relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching`. IOW, you can make sure that you do fetch everything in "one go."

Andrew